# revere array object based on year and month

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have bellow array object

```
var dataset = [
               {
                "data" : "Country",
                "title" : "country"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Jan 2023",
                "title" : "Jan 2023"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Feb 2023",
                "title" : "Feb 2023"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Dec 2022",
                "title" : "Dec 2022"
               },
               ]
```

what i want is to keep the first index as it is by year 2022 then followed by 2023 in month order like below

```
var dataset = [
               {
                "data" : "Country",
                "title" : "country"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Dec 2022",
                "title" : "Dec 2022"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Jan 2023",
                "title" : "Jan 2023"
               },
               {
                "data" : "Feb 2023",
                "title" : "Feb 2023"
               },

               ]
```

so for example if 2022 Nov is then Nov should come fist then Dec 2022. the original array already sorted with latest year first then followed by last year. so means original array always has latest year month first.

i try array sort but was not able archive

```
 var newdataset  = dataset.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a !== columns[0] && b !== columns[0]) { 
      return b.data.length - a.data.length
      }
  })
```

Comment: Please share you attempt with array sort. How did it fall short of your expectations? You will likely need a custom sort function since you have specific requirements for your sort.

Comment: What is `columns` in your script?

Comment: @mykaf i've already answer my question you can see in bellow also answer from other people. so please ignore thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the date values constructed from each dataset data.

```js
let dataset = [{
    "data": "Country",
    "title": "country"
  },
  {
    "data": "Feb 2023",
    "title": "Feb 2023"
  },
  {
    "data": "Dec 2022",
    "title": "Dec 2022"
  },
  {
    "data": "Jan 2023",
    "title": "Jan 2023"
  },
  {
    "data": "Nov 2022",
    "title": "Nov 2022"
  },
]

const [heading, ...rest] = dataset;

dataset = [heading, ...rest.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.data) - new Date(b.data);
})];

console.log(dataset);
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the values by date you should convert them to `Date` objects within your custom `sort()` logic. Then you can compare them more accurately than you are currently doing by string comparison.

Here's a full working example:

```js
const dataset = [{
  "data": "Country",
  "title": "country"
}, {
  "data": "Jan 2023",
  "title": "Jan 2023"
}, {
  "data": "Feb 2023",
  "title": "Feb 2023"
}, {
  "data": "Dec 2022",
  "title": "Dec 2022"
}]

const sortedDataset = dataset.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.data) - new Date(b.data));
console.log(sortedDataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do this by using bellow code

```
 const sortByMonth = arr => {
      const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      const getIndexOfMonth = month => months.indexOf(month)
      return [ ...arr ].sort((left, right) => {
        const [ leftMonth, leftYear ] = left.title.split(' ')
        const [ rightMonth, rightYear ] = right.title.split(' ')
        if (leftYear !== rightYear) {
          return parseInt(leftYear) - parseInt(rightYear)
        }
        return getIndexOfMonth(leftMonth) - getIndexOfMonth(rightMonth)
      })
    }

    console.log(sortByMonth(dataset))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).